# Background Worker Reuse Error C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, backgroundworker, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to learn how to use background workers for my project but i keep getting an error and i just cant figure out what to do. Within the designer i have created backgroundWorker1 and a button.

```
private void btnNewSchedule_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw = backgroundWorker1;
        Scheduletest(bw);

    }
private void Scheduletest(BackgroundWorker bw)
    {
     //junk code

     //do the expensive coding part now
        bw.RunWorkerAsync();

    }
```

When i click the button to run the worker once, it works fine, but upon a second click, i get the error of 
"This operation has already had OperationCompleted called on it and further calls are illegal"

I read that i have to make a new instance of background worker each time, and thats what i tried to do with the bw backgroundworker, but i assume that part is not correct. Can someone please help me to be able to reuse this button?

Great Thanks

Comment: You cannot reused a backgroundworker like that--as soon as the state transitions to "completed" it's 'done'.

Comment: @GrantWinney Im attempting to yes. I read thats the correct way to accomplish my task. Frankly, im just trying to click the button and have it work every time. Whatever i must do to accomplish this is ultimately my goal. Open to alternatives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you've done is indeed create a new instance, but then you went and reassigned the old one.

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw = backgroundWorker1;
```

So now, `bw` doesn't contain the new instance, but the old instance. Here's how to do it properly:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
Scheduletest(bw);
```

Comment: The thing about this is, bw is just a blank backgroundworker. the one i programmed in the designer, backgroundworker1, has event handlers that i have set, which is why i was trying to do the bw=backgroundWorker1 part. Is there some way to accomplish this?

Comment: You'll need to reassign your event handlers each time you instantiate a new background worker.